# The confusing array.new_float is not the same as imagined

Tags: pine-script

According to the help of tradeview

`array. new_float(size, initial_value)`

It should be to create an array with a length of size, and the initial value is initial_value.
But the following code I wrote

```
var rfilt = array. new_float(2, close)
plot(array. get(rfilt, 0), title = "rfilt(0)")
plot(array. get(rfilt, 1), title = "rfilt(1)")
```

When close is 3695, I think the two values of the array should be 3695, but it shows 3701 and 3701

May I ask how is this going? Thanks!

Here are the other days result.

```
N day, close=3705, the array is 3630 and 3630
N+1 day, close=3755, the array is 3641 and 3630
N+2 days, close=3765, the array is 3690 and 3641
N+3 days, close=3730, the array is 3701 and 3690
N+4 days, close=3700, the array is 3701 and 3701
N+5 days, close=3695, the array is 3701 and 3701
```

May I ask how is this going? Thanks!